# IOS Safari transition transform not working

Tags: css, safari, css-transitions, vendor-prefix

Whenever I seem to apply some code to let's say move a div for example using the latest iOS Safari browser it doesn't actually transition between the two rules set. I have tried changing to use other than percentage values but still to this day, I have never been able to get it to work when I use `transition: transform;` for any `translate` property applied.

I'm using the correct prefixes and checked support and should be working no problem.

http://caniuse.com/#search=transition

http://caniuse.com/#search=translate

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/95y4pejs/1/)

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('.mydiv').toggleClass('added-class');
});
```

```css
.mydiv {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;

    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transition: transform 0.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: transform 0.6s ease-out; 
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-out;
}

.added-class {
    -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
    -o-transform: translateY(100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mydiv"></div>
<button type="button">Toggle class</button>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Old versions of iOS Safari support only vendor-prefixed properties and values for `transition` and `transform`, so you should use `-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform` instead `-webkit-transition: transform`:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/tbdr0o9b/3/)

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('.mydiv').toggleClass('added-class');
});
```

```css
.mydiv {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: transform 0.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: transform 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-out;
}

.added-class {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
    -o-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mydiv"></div>
<button type="button">Toggle class</button>
```

Comment: Seems to do the trick, thank you Sergey! 
The transition works perfect now (tested on iPhone 6 iOS8).

Comment: You saved my day trying to target a bug in iOS 15 where transform: translateX(-50%) did not work.