# css transition not working in mobile chrome

Tags: css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to scale an image with css transition upon clicking some text.

The checkmark image should animate out and in each time the link is clicked.  In iPhone Chrome however the checkmark doesn't animate - simply jumps from one state to the other, seemingly ignoring the css {transition: transform 200ms}.

It seems to work everywhere except iPhone Chrome browser - I've gone through everything as best as I can but it's totally stumped me!

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqBJzr

**CSS:**

```
.checkmark {
    width: 35px;
    -webkit-transition: transform 200ms;
    transition: all 200ms;
}

.checkmark.scale {
    -webkit-transform: scale(3);
    transform: scale(3);
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function checkMarkAnim() {

    $('.checkmark').toggleClass('scale');

}
```

Any pointers on what has gone wrong would really help.

Thank you in advance

## Update:

The suggestion to add `-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;` does not seem to have resolved the problem (although I initially thought it had).

Comment: Did you try `-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;`?

Comment: Yep, that should work. Due to Apple's restrictions, Chrome uses older webkit (same as Safari) on iOS, and it supports only vendor-prefixed transform. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128587/ios-safari-transition-transform-not-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS Safari transition transform not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128587/ios-safari-transition-transform-not-working)

Comment: Thank you @adpro!  Yes, that does seem to work!

I had tried: -webkit-transition: transform 200ms;

I didn't realise it needed -webkit-transform

Comment: Glad I could help. Even though the possible duplicate isn't exactly the same (without mention of Chrome) it is best to keep this question around and have it marked as duplicate so more people with your exact issue can find the solution.  And welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: Oops - actually it doesn't appear to have solved it - I accidentally checked it in Safari instead of Chrome.  I updated the Codepen with `-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;` to test it

Comment: I just ran into this too, looks like this was earlier this year, did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: @Misterparker sorry, unfortunately not

Comment: @HMS any updates?

Comment: any solutions? transforms work on my website initally in ios chrome, but stop working after a while. after a restart it works again. desktop chrome or android chrome do not have this issue, this is clearly a chrome bug on ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please also add/keep `-webkit-transition: transform 200ms;`. So in the end you should have:

```css
.checkmark {
    width: 35px;
    -webkit-transition: transform 200ms;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms
    transition: all 200ms;
}

.checkmark.scale {
    -webkit-transform: scale(3);
    transform: scale(3);
}
```

See it here working with mobile chrome (iOS): https://codepen.io/miikaeru/pen/aMXYEb

Answer (score 85):

After a few days of searching what actually worked for me is **just Chrome restart**.

Comment: Funny, it worked as well for me. My css transform transition wasn't doing any animation no matter what, but only in Chrome for iOS. Out of despair I even tried to use the old -webkit rule and values, but it didn't help. But then I forced it to a fresh start and it worked again.

Comment: Indeed, same here. Funny …

Comment: Same thing here.

Comment: This is clearly a chrome issue, i wonder when it will be fixed…

Comment: I didn't believe it would work, but... It worked

Comment: I spent like 15 minutes trying to debug my CSS, and it turns out that it was Chrome issue on iOS. Force killing and re-launching the Chrome did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone skeptical, don't dismiss this answer — it works.

Comment: Also worked for me... my mobile Chrome has had a lot of issues with animations/transitions, not sure why

Comment: I can't believe this worked... Ironically, it worked fine on mobile Safari but not Chrome (until restarting Chrome).

Comment: Here to add that this answer 100% works.

Comment: it works yes, but is it a solution? shall i just add a note to my website that mentions to restart the browser everytime animation stop working?

Comment: It's really annoying. I have to do this multiple times a day since I'm working as a front-end dev and need to test on IOS.

Comment: Worked like a charm, be blessed

Comment: Lol. I swapped out an entire JS plugin just because of this 

Comment: Why is this still a thing in 2023?

Comment: Crazy. Worked like a charm for me. I use Edge on my iOS-device.

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by a known issue in iOS.

For more information, see: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=228333
and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1231712